# Subscategory have problem with filters

Tags: product, filter

In my store > `main category` filters are ok (type, size, price), but when access by `subcategory`, appears only the filter (type product). I need the same filters appear in all `categories / subcategories`.

**What's the problem and how an i fixed it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  you need to  check that  ***magento subcategories Anchor setting is  Yes***.

See it setting (`admin>Catalog > Manage Categories > Category name > Display settings >Anchor)`

Checkout more details [at  here](https://kb.magenting.com/content/13/60/en/magento-is-anchor-option-in-category-properties.html%60)